# LINQ Aggregate and GroupBy determining correct data 

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `List<ShipmentInformation>`

```
public class ShipmentInformation
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public long StartID { get; set; }
    public long EndID { get; set; }
    public DateTime BoxDate { get; set; }
}
```

I currently have this code to determine where the most stock is:

```
var TypeTotals = shipmentInfo.GroupBy(x => x.Type).Select(x => new { Type = x.Key, Total = x.Sum(y => (y.EndID - y.StartID) + 1) });

//Select the one with the largest amount of stock
var LargestType = TypeTotals.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Total > r.Total ? l : r).Chip;
```

However if the totals are exactly the same it will select the last item in `TypeTotals` so I now want to add a check in to make sure that the earliest `BoxDate` is used.

So lets say I have 10 items of Type A and 10 items of Type B, at the moment Type B will be chosen.

I want to now make sure that when I return the `LargestType` that it returns the earliest item with that type. So if any of my items in A have a BoxDate earlier than any of the items in B then A should be chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save the minimum date for each type total and then take it into account in your aggregation (which by the way would be cleaner with a simple `foreach` loop in my opinion)

```
var TypeTotals = shipmentInfo.GroupBy(x => x.Type)
                             .Select(x => new 
                             { 
                               Type = x.Key, 
                               Total = x.Sum(y => (y.EndID - y.StartID) + 1), 
                               Date = x.Min(z=> z.BoxDate) 
                             });

var LargestType = TypeTotals.Aggregate((l, r) =>
{
 if(l.Total > r.Total)
   return l;
 else if(l.Total == r.Total)
   return l.Date < r.Date ?  l : r;
 else return r;
}).Chip;
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the min date to the anonymous class.  And instead of an aggregate, use OrderBy and First.

```
var TypeTotals = shipmentInfo
                     .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
                     .Select(x => new 
                                  {
                                      Type = x.Key,
                                      Total = x.Sum(y => (y.EndID - y.StartID) + 1),
                                      MinBoxDate = x.Min(z => z.BoxDate)
                                  });

//Select the one with the largest amount of stock
var LargestType = TypeTotals
                      .OrderByDescending(l => l.Total)
                      .ThenBy(l => l.MinBoxDate)
                      .First().Chip;
```